# Linker error in C when using Postgres

Tags: c, postgresql, linker, linker-errors

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//Start connection
PGconn* connection = PQconnectdb("host=webcourse.cs.nuim.ie dbname=cs621  sslmode=require user=ggales password=1234");

if (PQstatus(connection) ==CONNECTION_BAD)
{
printf("Connection error\n");
PQfinish(connection);
return -1; //Execution of the program will stop here
}
printf("Connection ok\n");
//End connection
PQfinish(connection);
printf("Disconnected\n");


return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/cc73kO0N.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
main.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `PQstatus'
main.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
main.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is strange, as PQconnectdb etc are all functions that are defined in libpq-fe.h, which I have already included in the code.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`#include <libpq-fe.h>` does not link to the library, it only includes information about the functions and data types that the library provides.

You must tell the linker where the references that are declared in `libpq-fe.h` can actually be found.

If you are using a Makefile to compile you code you should add `-lpq` to your `LDFLAGS` or linking command.

Post the command you are running to compile to give us more information.

Comment: On Mac, there's a `/usr/lib/libpq.dylib` (where `.dylib` is the analogue of `.so` on Linux and `.dll` on Windows).  The library might be as simple as `-lpq` therefore.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Correct, it's libpq, just `-lpq`.